# 500 Internal Server Error with Rails Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, production-environment

I recently uploaded some new files to my production server (and overriding the old ones) and am now getting 500 Internal Server Error. The server is running phusion passenger (even though I am not getting that error message anymore) and in my local test environment everything seems to be working fine.

Here is the site:  http://www.pandonews.com/

When I looked in my apache log i see this error:

```
[ pid=3106 thr=140057117177664 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:884 time=2013-09-01 17:37:24.84 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/var/www/feedme': The spawn server died unexpectedly, and restarting it failed.
  Backtrace:
     in 'virtual Passenger::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Client.h:742)
     in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:312)
     in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:585)
```

I have no idea what the problem is. It has been running fine up until now. I don't really know where to start in order to fix this. I tried running gem passenger install again but nothing happened.

Recent activities:

- Installed pg gem (but removed it from gem file after deciding to stay with sqlite3 for now) the yml file should be ok...
- Tried running bundle update on server and locally but it keeps hanging
- Changed some javascript and css files...
- Tried resetting the server with RAILS_ENV=production rake:db reset - no change!

**EDIT:**
when running rails s production i get the following error:

```
/home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/production (LoadError)
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:63:in `try_require'
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `server'
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/otto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**EDIT2:**

```
$ passenger-status
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.
```

**EDIT3:**
Seems like it is running, still internal server error:

```
passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d -e production
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started =============== 
PID file: /var/www/feedme/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /var/www/feedme/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

Serving in the background as a daemon.
===============================================================================
otto@scraper:/var/www/feedme$ passenger status
Phusion Passenger Standalone is running on PID 18788, according to PID file /var/www/feedme/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
otto@scraper:/var/www/feedme$
```

Comment: and what appears on your production log? What happens if you try to lunch the application manually, like `rails s production`, logged in with the user that usually runs the rails processes?

Comment: Are all the rails gems on 3.2.7? Seems like it could be a version incompatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Did the following:

1. gem install passenger (no sudo or anything)
2. Find root: passenger-config –root
3. Give chmod to all from root until username folder: sudo chmod -R 777 /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-4.0.14 to every folder until /home/username/
4. passenger-install-apache2-module (without anything)
5. Take the code you are given paste it inside: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
6. sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: current -root does not work it its passenger-config --root

Comment: Use "passenger-config validate-install"  it should guide you into fixing your passenger setup.